# How can i change the name of input file(finger.dat) in a src dir by adding prefix (finger.dat_temp) in destination directory) while copying?

Tags: python

How can i change the name of input file(finger.dat) in a src dir by adding prefix (finger.dat_temp) in destination directory) while copying multiple files from one directory to other???

Comment: what have you tried... also its not very clear what you want from this question...

Comment: Also, `_temp` is a suffix... </nitpick>

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in list:
    shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dest_dir, file + "_temp"))
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Sorry fr my mistake, i was in hurry n i couldn't put up my question in a proper way,but thanks for all those who had tym to view n answer my question :)!!